# Dynamic Instance in DBA Directories

Tags: oracle, clone, database-administration

**Disclaimer: I'm not a DBA, just a DBA-wannabe.**

I have created a Directory in our Production Environment:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY PAY_FOLDER AS '/u01/EBSPROD/apps/apps_st/appl/cust/12.0.0/per/1.0';
GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY PAY_FOLDER TO PUBLIC;
```

However, when our Production Environment is cloned to a Non-Prod Instance (for example EBSDEV),
the instance name doesn't change and still stays as EBSPROD.
I would want it to be:
`/u01/EBSDEV/apps/apps_st/appl/cust/12.0.0/per/1.0` when cloned over to DEV
`/u01/EBSDEV/apps/apps_st/appl/cust/12.0.0/per/1.0` when cloned over to TEST
`/u01/EBSUAT/apps/apps_st/appl/cust/12.0.0/per/1.0` when cloned over to UAT

Do I need a separate script to re-create these directories when i clone an instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The directory name is just a string; it does not know that you have embedded the instance name.

Use

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY directory_name AS'path_name';
```

instead of a DROP-Statement followed by a CREATE-Statement.  This will keep all the grants on this directory.

It should not be too hard to create a single parameterized script that would take the DB Name or Instance name (whichever is appropriate) and build the correct directory name.